# How could HTML get response "request.form.username" from Python code?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I think when I request id/password to the server, back-end code couldn't response `{{request.form.username}}` in html.
Because there is not "request.form.username" in the render_template's parameter.

But still, the HTML code on the below could read `{{ request.form.username}}`.

So, I wanna know what I am missing now.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
     request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or \
                request.form['password'] != 'secret':
            error = 'Invalid credentials'
        else:
            flash(u'Invalid password provided', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5500")
```

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <h1>Login</h1>
  {% if error %}
    <p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
  {% endif %}
  <form method=post>
    <dl>
      <dt>Username:
      <dd><input type=text name=username value="{{request.form.username }}">

      <dt>Password:
      <dd><input type=password name=password>
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value=Login>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Oh, I've got one hint from [Flask docs with Rendering Templates keyword](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).

which is saying "inside templates you also have access to the request, session and g1 objects as well as the get_flashed_messages() function"

Among those objects `{{request.form.username}}` is included in request object.
That's why It could happen.